# When installing Porto theme in magento2 cannot import statics blocks

Tags: magento2

Hi I am very new to Magento, and I am trying to install the proto theme, I have activated the theme, add the demo which I want, overwritten cms pages, and now when I try to import static block, it gives an error,

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `cms_block` (`block_id`, `title`, `identifier`, `content`, `is_active`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually export/import the cms_block and cms_page's database tables using MySQLDump or PHPMyAdmin.
All the data you need should be in those two tables.
However, the DB tables involved are:

1. cms_block
2. cms_block_store
3. cms_page
4. cms_page_store